# Puppet and Mysql 5.5

Tags: mysql, puppet

**The Background**

I am using Centos 6.5 with Puppet 3.7.3.

I've installed the module puppetlabs-mysql v3.1.0

Centos 6.5 comes with MySql 5.1.73 installed by default. What I'd like to achieve is to upgrade that version via Puppet to 5.5.40, using the module described above

**The initial Solution**

Well, I couldn't find a proper solution to do this. The official documentation only tells how to configure the puppet manifest *in order to have MySql installed*, not taking into account the version. That doesn't suit me because the version remains unchanged after running the puppet agent.

```
package { "MySQL-client": ensure => installed }
```

**Solution #1 found on Internet Forums**

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15424520/install-mysql-via-puppet/15890020#15890020).

```
package {
    'mysql-client-core-5.5': ensure => present
}
```

With that solution, I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Execution of '/usr/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y list mysql-client-core-5.5' 
returned 1: Error: No matching Packages to list
```

**Solution #2 found on Internet Forums**

Found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/723936/how-to-ensure-version-5-5-for-mysql-with-puppet).

It is actually proposing two solutions:

```
package { 'mysql-server' : ensure => '5.5' , }
```

and

```
package { 'mysql55w' : ensure => 'present' , }
```

In both cases I am getting a similar error, which is no other than *package not found on the current installed repos*

In order to fix all the problems above, I successfully added the necessary changes on the puppet manifest to install the repo where MySQL 5.5.40 lives.

After repuppetting again, I am now getting a different error:

```
Error: mysql55w-libs conflicts with mysql-libs-5.1.73-3.el6_5.i686
```

Of course, the old libraries are conflicting with the new ones. Fortunately, there is a workaround for this, as described [here](https://webtatic.com/packages/mysql55/). I successfully added those commands to my puppet manifest (using the EXEC command)

```
yum install mysql.`uname -i` yum-plugin-replace
yum replace mysql --replace-with mysql55w
```

After all these workarounds, my puppet manifest executes fine, but only after chaining each declaration to execute it sequentially (puppet doesn't assume order). Otherwise, it may try to install Mysql 5.5 before to install the repo or before to change the libraries.

**The Question**

Well, the question is, is there any other way to manage this more gracefully in puppet?

It wasn't enough to tell puppet that I wanted MySQL installed. I actually had to tell Puppet how to do it.

My Puppet manifest looks like the good old fashion scripts that Puppet is supposed to replace. I can't concentrate in *what I want*. I had to instruct *it how to achieve it too*

Comment: You can specify the package version in the puppetlabs-mysql module using the `package_ensure` variable, but the solution I give below is probably better for you! :)

Answer (score 2):

Even with configuration management package-providers can be a headache! :)

However, in this instance we can leverage the work by using a pre-existing module to manage Yum: [example42/yum](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/example42/yum)

Install the module like so:

```
puppet module install example42/yum
```

With this, it becomes much easier to manage, and you can install MySQL 5.5 much cleaner and idempotently:

```
  class { 'yum':
    defaultrepo => false,
    extrarepo   => '' ,
  }

  class { 'yum::repo::mysql_community':
    enabled_version => '5.5',
  }

  package { 'mysql-community-server':
    ensure  => '5.5.42-2.el6',
    require => Class['yum::repo::mysql_community'],
  }
```

As you can see, the only ordering used is the `require` on the package, to make sure the Yum repo has been setup before trying to install it.

Worked for me on a brand new Centos 6.6 Vagrant box:

```
# Vagrantfile
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "puppetlabs/centos-6.6-64-puppet"

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "puppet module install example42/yum"

  config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "./"
    puppet.manifest_file  = "default.pp"
  end

end
```

Output:

```
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: Notice: Preparing to install into /etc/puppet/modules ...
==> default: Notice: Downloading from https://forgeapi.puppetlabs.com ...
==> default: Notice: Installing -- do not interrupt ...
==> default: /etc/puppet/modules
==> default: └─┬ example42-yum (v2.1.17)
==> default:   └── example42-puppi (v2.1.10)
==> default: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> default: Running Puppet with default.pp...
==> default: Notice: Compiled catalog for localhost.home in environment production in 0.85 seconds
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Yum::Repo::Mysql_community/Yum::Managed_yumrepo[mysql-connectors-community]/File[/etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-mysql]/ensure: defined content as '{md5}26b9ed77a3a087874a27103c1f9d6a6f'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Yum::Repo::Mysql_community/Yum::Managed_yumrepo[mysql-tools-community]/File[/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-tools-community.repo]/ensure: created
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Yum::Repo::Mysql_community/Yum::Managed_yumrepo[mysql56-community]/File[/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql56-community.repo]/ensure: created
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Yum::Repo::Mysql_community/Yum::Managed_yumrepo[mysql56-community]/Yumrepo[mysql56-community]/ensure: created
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Yum::Repo::Mysql_community/Yum::Managed_yumrepo[mysql57-community-dmr]/File[/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql57-community-dmr.repo]/ensure: created
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Yum::Repo::Mysql_community/Yum::Managed_yumrepo[mysql57-community-dmr]/Yumrepo[mysql57-community-dmr]/ensure: created
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Yum::Repo::Mysql_community/Yum::Managed_yumrepo[mysql-connectors-community]/File[/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql-connectors-community.repo]/ensure: created
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Yum::Repo::Mysql_community/Yum::Managed_yumrepo[mysql-connectors-community]/Yumrepo[mysql-connectors-community]/ensure: created
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Yum::Prerequisites/Yum::Plugin[priorities]/Package[yum-plugin-priorities]/ensure: created
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Yum::Repo::Mysql_community/Yum::Managed_yumrepo[mysql-tools-community]/Yumrepo[mysql-tools-community]/ensure: created
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Yum::Repo::Mysql_community/Yum::Managed_yumrepo[mysql55-community]/File[/etc/yum.repos.d/mysql55-community.repo]/ensure: created
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Yum::Repo::Mysql_community/Yum::Managed_yumrepo[mysql55-community]/Yumrepo[mysql55-community]/ensure: created
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Main/Node[default]/Package[mysql-community-server]/ensure: created
==> default: Notice: Finished catalog run in 63.97 seconds
```

Comment: Peter Souter: I didn't test your solution, but my final solution is quite similar. However, I used the class ::mysql::server, which has a property "package_ensure", for which I specified '5.5.41-1.el6.remi'

Comment: Ah ok, yes I was going to suggest using package ensure, but I wasn't sure if you had the repos setup for that specific package. Could you accept my answer? :)

Comment: Can you click the little tick as well?